# Missing reference to MSTSCLib when porting WPF app to NetCore 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

Trying to help a colleague porting a WPF app from NetFramework 4.7.2 to NetCore 3.
I have a problem with DLL referencies. The original project has a reference to:
AxMSTSClib 
and
MSTSCLib

I was able to add reference to AxMSTSClib but I don't know how to add reference to MSTSCLib.
Even if I add COM Interop MSTSCLib, I keep having this error:

[image: error]

caused by this code:

```
private readonly RemoteDesktopSessionInfo _rdpSessionInfo;

[...]

RdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.RDPPort = _rdpSessionInfo.Port;
```

Where 
    RdpClient is

```
internal AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting RdpClient;
```

Anything I can do?

EDIT:
this what my project reference looks like:

[image]
Thanks
Gianpaolo

Comment: Have you registered the library using `regsrv32`? Is `EmbedInteropTypes` set to `true` also?

Comment: @pavel hello! I tried setting the flag to true but it didn't help. I don't know how to use regsrv32 but ill Google up and try...

Comment: Never do that, this component is registered by Windows Setup.  Hard to guess why you have this problem, works just fine in a .NETCore v2.2 project.  Well, it builds, doesn't run at all of course.  It really does look like you forgot to add the reference.  Don't be misled by MSTSCLib.dll showing up in the Solution Explorer window, you must have MSTSCLib show up inside the Reference node of the project.

Comment: @HansPassant hello. I  have added a pic of the project reference. Can you look to see if it si ok? I feel dumb :/

Comment: All I see is yet another good reason to wait with .NETCore v3.0 until it gets stable.  Why it is named "Interop.MSTSCLib" instead of just plain "MSTSCLib" (as aximp.exe would do) is not obvious to me.  But aximp.exe is not ported to .NETCore and you didn't tell us how you obtained these assemblies.  Best to [post here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues).

Comment: @HansPassant since it was not compiling I've tried referencing the assembly by creating a folder and copy-pasting dll in there. Just to give it a try. I'll follow your subgestion and wait, I don't want to get crazy for nothing. Thank you very much.